# Why does this 'scroll to top' script cause a type error? jQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more jQuery woes, in that my scroll to the top script isn't working.

I've tried numerous scripts but each time I get the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$target.offset().top')

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn(); 
        } else { 
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut(); 
        } 
    }); 
    $('.scrollup').click(function(){ 
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

This is used on a Wordpress site, and Wordpress loads jQuery in no conflict mode.

jQuery really is the bane of my life at the moment. Thanks.

EDIT:

It looks like it's conflicting with this, which is also on the same page. I need both to work side by side.

```
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 50
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Since the event is on `$(window)`, `this` is the window, so `$(this).scrollTop()` is trying to get the scroll position of the window, which is wrong...

Comment: Ah. I also have `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var target = this.hash;
     var $target = $(target);

     $('html, body').stop().animate({
         'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
     }, 900, 'swing', function () {
         window.location.hash = target;
     });
 });
}); ` on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its jQuery compatibility issue. In your script use 'jQuery' instead of '$' wherever you are using it.

Comment: Shouldn't `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ `
take case of that?